# Recorrer Json tomando parte de los valores

Tags: c#, json

Tengo este ejemplo de estructura de Json

```
[
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 256,
    "Destino": "Actividades Comunitarias",
    "Tipo de Solicitante": "-",
    "Superficie Otorgada": "",
    "Lugar de Firma": "",
    "Fecha de Firma": ""
  },
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 263,
    "Destino": null,
    "Tipo de Solicitante": null,
    "Superficie Otorgada": null,
    "Lugar de Firma": null,
    "Fecha de Firma": null
  },
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 266,
    "Destino": "Cultura",
    "Tipo de Solicitante": "Civil",
    "Superficie Otorgada": "17",
    "Lugar de Firma": "",
    "Fecha de Firma": "21/06/2015"
  },
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 270,
    "Destino": null,
    "Tipo de Solicitante": null,
    "Superficie Otorgada": valor,
    "Lugar de Firma": "",
    "Fecha de Firma": null
  },
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 273,
    "Destino": null,
    "Tipo de Solicitante": null,
    "Superficie Otorgada": null,
    "Lugar de Firma": null,
    "Fecha de Firma": null
  },
  {
    "idgoOperacion": 274,
    "Destino": null,
    "Tipo de Solicitante": null,
    "Superficie Otorgada": valor,
    "Lugar de Firma": valor,
    "Fecha de Firma": valor
  }]
```

y tengo una tabla con dos campos, idgoOperacion, Json.

Necesito guardar el json de la siguiente forma por cada numero de operacion y asi sucesivamente

```
idgoOperacion = 256
Json = {"idgoOperacion": 256,"Destino": "Actividades Comunitarias",     
         "Tipo de Solicitante": "-","Superficie Otorgada": "","Lugar de 
         Firma": "","Fecha de Firma": ""}
```

y asi sucesivamente.

intente obtener el valor del Json de la siguiente forma pero no logre recorrer el json completo y poder obtener el valor de idgoOperacion.

```
JArray jsonPreservar = JArray.Parse(jsonText);
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonPreservar[0].ToString());
```

Comment: que es lo que tiene data?

Comment: porque usas un dynamic?

Comment: data contiene {"idgoOperacion": 256,"Destino": "Actividades Comunitarias",     
         "Tipo de Solicitante": "-","Superficie Otorgada": "","Lugar de 
         Firma": "","Fecha de Firma": ""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes recorrer el arreglo completo, asi puedes obtener todos los valores de las propiedades

```
JArray jsonPreservar = JArray.Parse(jsonText);
foreach (JObject jsonOperaciones in jsonPreservar.Children<JObject>())
{
    //Aqui para poder identificar las propiedades y sus valores
    /*foreach (JProperty jsonOPropiedades in jsonOperaciones.Properties())
    {
        string propiedad = jsonOPropiedades.Name;
        if (propiedad.Equals("idgoOperacion"))
        {
            var idgoOperacion = Convert.ToInt32(jsonOPropiedades.Value);
        }
    }*/
    //Aqui puedes acceder al objeto y obtener sus valores
    var idgoOperacion = Convert.ToInt32(jsonOperaciones["idgoOperacion"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario usar `dynamic` ya que devuelve un tipo `JObject` y de ahi necesitas obtener `idgoOperacion` de tu objeto en el json

lo cual

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonPreservar[0].ToString());
var id = Convert.ToInt32(data["idgoOperacion"]);
```

Comment: si funciona correctamente, en data obtengo {"idgoOperacion": 256,"Destino": "Actividades Comunitarias", "Tipo de Solicitante": "-","Superficie Otorgada": "","Lugar de Firma": "","Fecha de Firma": ""} y en id el 256, como puedo recorrer todo el json?

Comment: recorres el JArray con un for y por cada interacción asignas el JObject y aplicas la lógica que necesitas.